How to Input date correctly in Investing.com?
I am trying to input a date range using a date variable type and the command .send_keys("inputDate") where "inputDate" is a string value like "2020-01-02", but even when the code run correctly, the date value inputted is totally  different from the date I wanted.
I have tried to switch variable types from Str to date using "from datetime import datetime" or "import date" and I was hoping it would fix the issue, but it didn't. I have also inspected directly the input field in the website, which is the following line:
<input class="absolute left-0 top-0 h-full w-full opacity-0" type="date" max="2024-05-29" value="2024-04-28">

and also it's XPath:
//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/input

and checked if the order of input (day-month-year) was correct. Still didn't work.
There is no error code, it just inputs the wrong date
Here's my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from datetime import date

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
opt.add_argument("--enable-javascript")

prefs = {"download.default_directory": "Downloads"}  # Change this to your desired directory
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
opt.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["disable-popup-blocking"])

userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

opt.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opt)  # 16
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.removeScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {"identifier":"1"})

driver.get(r'https://www.investing.com/portfolio');
assert 'Portfolio & Watchlist - Investing.com' in driver.title
print('Opened site successfully')

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loginFormUser_email')))
username.send_keys("", 'my Email')
print('Entered UserID')
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loginForm_password')))
password.send_keys("", 'my Password')
print('Entered Password')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,#Login
                     '//*[@id="signup"]/a').click()

links = ['https://www.investing.com/commodities/aluminum-historical-data',
         'https://www.investing.com/commodities/copper-historical-data?cid=959211',
         'https://www.investing.com/commodities/silver-historical-data',
         'https://www.investing.com/equities/steel-dynamics-historical-data',
         'https://www.investing.com/commodities/iron-ore-62-cfr-futures-historical-data'
         ]

for link in links:
    print(link)
    driver.get(link)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                         '//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                         '//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/input').send_keys('02-05-2022')
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                         '//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a/div').click()


If you don't show the python code generating the string then I'm totally unclear how you think we can answer this

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

You can try to go through JS to input
ele = .driver.find_element_by_xpath(your_xpath)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", ele, '2020-01-02')

